# How can I run this cron?

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks

I have some schedules that serve to clean the DB at certain times, but I want to use cron to run these times but when I try to run them in the windows schedule I get the following error:

```
 6 is not a valid position

      at C:\laragon\www\Sis\vendor\dragonmantank\cron-expression\src\Cron\FieldFactory.php:46
        42|                 case 4:
        43|                     $this->fields[$position] = new DayOfWeekField();
        44|                     break;
        45|                 default:
      > 46|                     throw new InvalidArgumentException(
        47|                         ($position + 1) . ' is not a valid position'
        48|                     );
        49|             }
        50|         }
    
      1   C:\laragon\www\Sis\vendor\dragonmantank\cron-expression\src\Cron\CronExpression.php:154
          Cron\FieldFactory::getField()
    
      2   C:\laragon\www\Sis\vendor\dragonmantank\cron-expression\src\Cron\CronExpression.php:137
          Cron\CronExpression::setPart("*")
```

And I do not have much experience with crons, as far as I know, it should take 6 asterisks and you specify in minutes, hours, days, months, how can I fix them?

This is the code:

```
 protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {
     $schedule->command('S:LA')->cron('0 23 4 1 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LC')->cron('0 23 4 2 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LC')->cron('0 23 4 6 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LC')->cron('0 23 4 10 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LD')->dailyAt('00:00');
    $schedule->command('S:LM')->monthlyOn(4, '23:00');
    $schedule->command('S:LS')->mondays()->at('23:00');
    $schedule->command('S:LSM')->cron('0 23 4 6 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LSM')->cron('0 23 4 1 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LT')->cron('0 23 4 1 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LT')->cron('0 23 4 3 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LT')->cron('0 23 4 6 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LT')->cron('0 23 4 9 * *');
    $schedule->command('S:LT')->cron('0 23 4 12 * *');
    
  }
```

Comment: [This](https://serverfault.com/a/449652) should answer your question, and you can test your expressions [here](https://crontab.guru/#5_4_*_*_*).

Comment: 5 asterisks , is what I'm trying to say.

Answer (score -1):

```
->cron('* * * * *');    Run the task on a custom Cron schedule
->everyMinute();    Run the task every minute
->everyTwoMinutes();    Run the task every two minutes
->everyThreeMinutes();  Run the task every three minutes
->everyFourMinutes();   Run the task every four minutes
->everyFiveMinutes();   Run the task every five minutes
->everyTenMinutes();    Run the task every ten minutes
->everyFifteenMinutes();    Run the task every fifteen minutes
->everyThirtyMinutes(); Run the task every thirty minutes
->hourly(); Run the task every hour
->hourlyAt(17); Run the task every hour at 17 minutes past the hour
->everyTwoHours();  Run the task every two hours
->everyThreeHours();    Run the task every three hours
->everyFourHours(); Run the task every four hours
->everySixHours();  Run the task every six hours
->daily();  Run the task every day at midnight
->dailyAt('13:00'); Run the task every day at 13:00
->twiceDaily(1, 13);    Run the task daily at 1:00 & 13:00
->weekly(); Run the task every sunday at 00:00
->weeklyOn(1, '8:00');  Run the task every week on Monday at 8:00
->monthly();    Run the task on the first day of every month at 00:00
->monthlyOn(4, '15:00');    Run the task every month on the 4th at 15:00
->quarterly();  Run the task on the first day of every quarter at 00:00
->yearly(); Run the task on the first day of every year at 00:00
->timezone('America/New_York'); Set the timezone
```

Comment: Explain your answer

Comment: These are the default laravel cron commands.  The very first one , ->cron('* * * * *');  only displays 5 values for a cron. Your commands in your example have 6 fields.